# Using Shackle to manage WoMan buffers

Tags: buffers, window-splitting

I would like `shackle.el` to manage the buffers created by `WoMan`.

Here's the configuration I'm using:

```
(use-package shackle
  :config
  (setq shackle-rules '((woman-mode :select t :align below :size 0.5)))
  (shackle-mode 1))
```

This should make `WoMan` buffers to appear on the bottom half of the screen.

But for some reason, `shackle` does not seem to work with the buffers created by `WoMan` (it works fine with other buffers, e.g., those that use `help-mode`).  Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this doesn't work. It seems that using the buffer's name instead of `woman-mode` and adding `:popup t` works:

```
(use-package shackle
  :config
  (setq shackle-rules '(("\\`\\*WoMan .*\\*\\'" :select t :popup t :align below :size 0.5)))
  (shackle-mode 1))
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem the other day. Don't remember exactly what was the major mode I was trying to tame, but `shackle` only worked when I used the buffer name. So, this is not specific to `woman-mode`.